# What's the real minimum RAM for running an instance of Neo4J

Tags: neo4j

I want to run as many instances of Neo4J (using the Enterprise version) on a single VM as possible. What are the real minimum RAM requirements to fire up an instance?

Right now TaskManager is telling me that Java.exe is taking about 70,000K (70 Meg). Does that sound right?

I'm not worried about the performance, I just want to stuff as many instances as possible on a single box so people can do some low demand search of their graph.

Answer (score 3):

One thing is what is recommended and second "it depends".

Neo4j is able to run on the Raspberry Pi. But you shouldn't expect great performance. Also I'm using AWS `t2.micro` for testing and it's enough.

Answer (score 2):

The size is bound to fluctuate as the graph is loaded into memory to perform traversals and when it is paged back to the disk (When memory is running out).

If I may offer up a suggestion, you could run only one database instance and have unconnected graphs for each of your users. This would very likely be far more efficient in terms of server resources.

For example, If you have say (:Item) nodes which make up a graph for each user,
you could have them instead label them as (:Item-User1) with a unique prefix or postfix for each user.

Thus when you want to alter the query to run for each user you could just add that unique element and search the graph.

The Idea is to have a separate sub-graph for each user which is unconnected to other user's sub-graphs. Instead of having a separate database instance for each Individual user. As long as each user's sub-graph is unconnected from other user's sub-graphs there should be no security vulnerability where a user is given access to another user's data.

This way you could potentially have infinite number of users (within reason. quite possibly in the millions of users) each with their own sub graphs, with potentially no loss in performance, instead of the handful of database instances you could spin up on a single VM, which are likely to be competing for resources and choking out.

Answer (score 0):

For neo4j 3.x, the [documented](http://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/#deployment) minimum memory requirement is 2GB.

Comment: Read that. But I'm running it on my desktop and the Java.exe is barely 70 meg. That's the source of my confusion.